# Mime utility decode word and text

Tags: java, mime, decoding

Mime utility decode

What is the difference between `MimeUtility.decodeWord()` and `MimeUtility.decodeText()`? 
please explain with a small example

Comment: there is no javadoc ?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html

decodeText

> decodeText(java.lang.String etext) 
>             Decode "unstructured" headers, that is, headers that are defined as '*text' as per RFC 822.

decodeWord

> decodeWord(java.lang.String eword) 
>             The string is parsed using the rules in RFC 2047 and RFC 2231 for parsing an "encoded-word".

Comment: Subject:  =?UTF-8?B?cHJhc2FubmE=?=  decodeText() workingfine decodeWord() throws Exception =?utf-8?q?this is some text?=    =?UTF-8?B?cHJhc2FubmE=?= decodeWord() works fine but decodeText() displays undecoded subject